# MSM Limitations

Tags: multi-site-manager, database, login, performance, sessions

We have a totally 20 Websites.

Right Now, We are running 5 websites all in MSM under single database. our requirements is member can access all websites in any one of web site login.

All are portal kind of websites.

Is it Right way for 20 Websites will run under Single database.
Any MSM limitation is there?

how will be a Performance?

I am eagerly waiting for suggestions

Comment: One limitation that you might run into is a MySQL table-width maximum. I've had this on an MSM install where each site had a large number of custom fields. IIRC we had a total over over 900 custom fields before we hit the issue, however.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is the right way. Performance will be the same, or similar, as if you had the same amount of traffic going through one website.

To be cautious you could try scaling up to the full 20 websites a few at a time. Check performance and if it's OK then add a few more.

You may also want to talk to Ellis Labs to see if you could switch your MSM licences to full EE licences should things not work out. They've been very helpful with me in the past regarding MSM licences.